# JavaScript Only - How to change the Font Size when clicked or rollover

Tags: javascript, css, fonts

This is what I'm trying to do. On my html page I have to have 4 different font sizes one that's `10px 20px 30px 40px` then reset.

When I click or rollover on `10px` the font size changes and displays the new size of the font in the `div` box.

I also have an input box so when I type in the input box and press submit it shows the text you typed in and displays it within the `div` box with the font assigned in the `CSS`.

Comment: Please, show your code in JSFiddle to us edit

Comment: What is the problem? Where is the code? Modern day browsers have zoom functions built in, I never understand why people do the font size adjustment.

Comment: zoom by browser sometimes make the style be broken since the 'zoom' not really zoom everything in the same way.

Comment: I need it for a school project, and my teacher wont help me with my questions

Comment: @MikeCollins - I've included my answer below. If there's anything you would like for me to change or if you have anymore questions, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may not be exactly what you're wanting, but it should get you started and it's a pure **JavaScript** solution:

**HTML**

```
<div id="fonts">
    <button value="10px">10px</button>
    <button value="20px">20px</button>
    <button value="30px">30px</button>
    <button value="40px">40px</button>
    <button value="15px">Reset</button>
</div>

<div id="text">The font size to change goes here</div>
```

You'll notice that I've set the `Reset` button to 15px, but I wasn't sure what the default font size should be in your case.

**Javascript**:

```
var text = document.getElementById("text");
var size = "15px";

var changeFontSize = function(e){
    var target = e.target;
    if(target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "button"){
        text.style.fontSize = target.value;
        if(e.type.toLowerCase() === "click"){
            size = target.value; 
        }    
    }
};

var mouseOut = function(e){
    text.style.fontSize = size;
}

document.addEventListener("click", changeFontSize, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseover", changeFontSize, false);
document.addEventListener("mouseout", mouseOut, false);
```

Depending on the browser compatibility you need to have, you may need to look into [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener) and [attachEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

When doing event handlers and messing with the `e` value, things get a bit tricky between browsers. This is mostly why the `jQuery` solutions are popular, since it generally takes care of the compatibility problems.

**[EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/9qHKw/8/)**

Comment: Thanks A lot ill try to work with this see if i can make it work

Comment: Sure, let me know if you need anything or if I can change it to work better in your situation. I'm currently at work, so my replies may be slightly delayed...but I'll be around. Good luck!

Comment: I tried this and it doesnt seem to work for me. honestly im a total newbie to javascript its like Chinese for me. I kind of get what you did, i tried the example it didnt work. i tried to fix it but im obv not good enough

Comment: The example on jsfiddle didn't work? Or when you tried to get it to work locally? What browser/version are you using?

Comment: both actually and im using firefox newest one

Comment: Ah yes, very possible. I'm using Chrome. I'll get you a working example shortly

Comment: The code has been update. Give it a shot and let me know if it works for ya. Thanks!

Comment: OMG You saved me, It works thanks so much i really appreciate it so much you dont understand I owe you big time

Comment: One Question when i input it into dreamweaver it wont work but with the site u gave me it works  text is nullLine: 15

Comment: I'm not very familiar with how dreamweaver does the javascript/html, but it seems that it's not getting a value for the first line of javascript `var text = document.getElementById("text");`. What this line does is gets an element in the HTML with an `id="text"`.

Comment: let me see if i can fix it

Comment: That's generally the best way I've found to learn...get your hands dirty and start figuring it out =) Don't worry, it'll get easier with time. Hang in there.

Comment: I know why it was not working for me lol i forgot to put onload

Answer (score 1):

bsAs for the HTML you want want something like this

```
<ul id="sizes">
    <li class="size" rel="10">10px</li>
    <li class="size" rel="20">20px</li>
    <li class="size" rel="30">30px</li>
    <li class="size" rel="40">40px</li>
    <li>
        <input class="manual" type="text" />
    </li>
<ul>
<div id="content">The font size to change goes here</div>
```

And for the jQuery

```
$( '#sizes' ).on({

    mouseover: function ( event ) {

        var $target = $( event.target );

        if ( $target.is( '.size' ) ) {
            $( '#content' ).css( 'font-size', $target.attr( 'rel' ) );
        }

    },
    blur: function ( event ) {

        var $target = $( event.target );

        if ( $target.is( '.manual' ) ) {
            $( '#content' ).css( 'font-size', parseInt( $target.val(), 10 ) );
        }

    }

});
```

That should be enough to get you started

Comment: I believe the OP wanted a `javascript only` solution.

Comment: Yeah javascript only please sorry its for a stupid school project and im finding it really hard and the teacher is not helping at all

Comment: Oh well, nothing wrong with JavaScript only, just so much easier with jQuery, hence it's there

Comment: For sure i understand but my teacher said javascript only so i have to do it that way thanks for the JQuery way

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started; a button that changes font size of a div, and a button that copies text from a textbox to the div:

```
<div id="demo"></div>

<input type="button" value="Size 10" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').style.fontSize='10px';" />

<input type="text" id="demotext" />
<input type="button" value="Use text" onclick="document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=document.getElementById('demotext').value;" />
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/AzmMc/

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wroing, it can't improve the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $("p1").mouseover(function(){
 $("p").css("fontsize","10px");
 });

 $("button ").onclick(function(){1
 $("p").css("fontsize","10px");
 });
```